# C -- Multiple Scanf Statements in a Switch Are Not Evaluated

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

I have a problem with some really basic C code for which I couldn't find a solution on any existing StackOverflow question.

The problem is simple: I have two `scanf` statements inside two different `cases` of a `switch` statement. The first statement is executed perfectly every time. The second, however, doesn't work, no matter which case the `switch` is evaluating.

Here's a tiny program I wrote to demonstrate the issue:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
int i = 0;

char *str1;
char *str2;
int state1, state2;
switch(i)
{
    case 0:
        state1 = scanf("%s", str1);
        getchar();
        break;
    case 1:
        state2 = scanf("%s", str2);
        getchar();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Something weird happened.\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("String 1: %s\nString 2: %s\nReturn 1: %d\nReturn 2: %d\n", str1, 
    str2, state1, state2); 

    return 0;
}
```

The `getchar`s are there to make sure it isn't an input overflow problem.

If I run that with `i = 0` with an input of `"hello"` then I get

```
String 1: hello
String 2: (null)
Return 1: 1
Return 2: 4195648
```

If run with `i = 1` and `"hello"` it outputs

```
String 1: 
String 2: (null)
Return 1: 0
Return 2: 0
```

As you can see, String 2 is never given a value despite running through that `case`.

This, to me, implies that the `switch` statement somehow runs through every `case` up to the matching one without actually evaluating what's inside, since both `state1` and `state2` are 0 in the second instance.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: `char *str1;
char *str2;` They do not point to valid areas. Change to like `char str1[32] = {0};`..`state1 = scanf("%31s", str1);`

Comment: You probably want to allocate some memory for the strings you are reading from the command line. Otherwise scanf just writes to the (undefined) memory addresses in str1 and str2.

Comment: Also `int state1, state2;` --> `int state1 = -999, state2 = -999;` To avoid using uninitialized variables.

Comment: Hm, well that was a suitably stupid thing to overlook when asking my very first SO question. Allocating space to the strings fixed it. Thanks. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: this kind of statement: `state1 = scanf("%s", str1);` is trying to set the contents where a pointer points; however, what is really needed is some memory allocation `char str1[20];'  and then the statement: `state1 = scanf("%19s", str1);` and the variable `state1` will contain 1 or 0 or EOF (read the `man` page for `scanf()` for the details)

Comment: the `getchar()` calls are only consuming the newline sequence, NOT avoiding input buffer overflows.  When using the %s input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  This will avoid input buffer overflows

Answer (score 0):

the variable `i` is only set to 0, so only the switch/case 0: will be evaluated.

The switch statement is never re-entered and the value of `i` is never updated, so no other switch/case will ever be evaluated/executed.

I suspect your idea of how a `switch` statement works is not quite correct.